# Django, Postgres - column cannot be cast automatically to type integer

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

In my database i have column:

```
currency = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to change this column from `CharField` to `IntegerField`. So in `models.py` i change this:

```
currency = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

then i made migrations: `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. After that actions it rise error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "currency" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
```

After that in pgAdmin3 console i made this changes:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN currency TYPE integer USING (currency::integer);
```

But i still got that error, I tried to change all back, but error doesn't disappear. What i have to do to escape this error. Thank you

Comment: A `ProgrammingError` is usually a message straight from Postgres. Double check that the column is now integer. Did you `commit` the transaction that altered the column type?

Comment: Do you already have data in your currency column?

Comment: No I haven't any data

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think django migrations does not perform casting, I looked in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/) but I did not find any thing about column casting.

- if the existing data is not that important for you, you can delete the column and create a new one

  1. first step remove currency from you model and apply migration
  2. add again the currency with the new definition and apply again the migration
- if you want to keep your data, you need to give your new column a different name and use the old column as a temporary column to hold the data during the transition.

**Important:** Postgresql is more strongly typed in recent versions, and as explained [here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20051229211409.GA9834@winnie.fuhr.org) some casting may not work in PosgreSQL unless it's explicitly done. And it required to be more specific about the type. So you have to make the right [choice](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html) based on your values:

```
alter table my_table alter column currency type bigint using currency::bigint
```

or maybe:

```
alter table my_table alter column currency type numeric(10,0) using currency::numeric
```

Comment: It is not about Django and migrations I guess rather about PostgreSQL - I had a similar problem some time ago with Integer -> Boolean conversion. What was working on SQLite didn't want to work on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 7):

It is a PSQL issue when changing from certain data types to others... I had a similar problem an I did something a bit hackey but it worked ... but only because I didn't have any important data in the column

1) delete the most recent migration for that app
2) delete/comment out the "column" on the object 
3) migrate the app with the missing column
4) reinstate/uncomment the offending "column"
5) migrate again

this is all a long way to delete and recreate the column on the actual db without using sql ... figured I would share in case it might help someone down the road

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer by @rafirosenberg, I had a similar issue and the fix was to delete migrations.  My specific error was:

```
"django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type double 
precision to geometry
LINE 1: ...COLUMN "gps" TYPE geometry(POINT,4326) USING 
"gps"::geometry..."
```

The problem was that I had run the inital migrations with the type as a FloatField.  So I had to go into the app in the file tree as demonstrated below, and deleted `0001_inital.py` and following migration files.  Then, running `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` both completed without problems.

```
- django-project
  - app0
  - app1
    - migrations
      __init__.py
      0001_inital.py
  - django-project
```